# How to get all the text excluding text with specific tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<w:body>
  <w:p w14:paraId="15812FB6" w14:textId="27A946A1" w:rsidR="001665B3" w:rsidRDefault="00771852">
    <w:r>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve">I am writing this </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T17:24:00Z" w:id="0">
      <w:r w:rsidR="00A1573E">
        <w:t>text to look</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-10-04T17:24:00Z" w:id="1">
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00A1573E">
        <w:delText>to test</w:delText>
      </w:r>
    </w:del>
...
```

I know that I get get all of the text using:

```
only_text_array = @file.search('//text()')
```

however, I actually want two text sets:

- One that contains all of the text except the text from the `<w:del>...</w:del>` elements.
- Another that contains all of the text except the text from the `<w:ins>...</w:ins>` elements.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following XPath :

```
//text()[not(ancestor::w:del or ancestor::w:ins)]
```

**<kbd>[`xpatheval demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5c88266b151845e52541019f2d9973e7)</kbd>**

This XPath returns all text nodes where none of the ancestor is `w:del` or `w:ins`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks har07.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="ignore">foobar</p>
    <p>Keep this</p>
    <p class="ignore2">foobar2</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

text1, text2 = %w[.ignore .ignore2].map do |s|
  tmp_doc = doc.dup
  tmp_doc.search(s).remove
  tmp_doc.text.strip
end

text1 # => "Keep this\n    foobar2"
text2 # => "foobar\n    Keep this"
```

It iterates over the list of selectors of things not wanted, `dup`s the document, then removes the undesirable nodes, and returns the text of the document after a bit of cleanup.

[`dup`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#dup-instance_method) does a deep-copy by default so the removal of nodes won't affect `doc`.